# Identify iconset

Tags: icons, appearance, icon-themes

I am using an Ubuntu System with a cool iconset, and I would love to know which one is it, to try it at home. But I have no idea how.

This is a sample:

[image]

If I look at "Settings > Appearance" this is what I get:

[image]

As you see `Theme` is emtpy.

I also tried looking for in under `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` and nothing.

What could I do?

Comment: Install `unity-tweak-tool` and look under Appearance / Icons.

Comment: @Jos could you please post that as an answer? Please don't post answers in comments since that means the question will never be marked as "answered".

Comment: @terdon I wasn't sure the OP had access to install tools. It appears he has, so there we go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to find out what themes and icon sets you are using, and to change them, is to install `unity-tweak-tool`.

In the main window, you have the "Themes" and "Icons" options.

Comment: This worked for me. Also, in case anyone wants to know, the theme is called Numix. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gsettings`:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme
```

And for the themes:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme
```